# What is the best configuration for building a cluster pc with a limited budget?

Tags: cluster-computing

I’m looking for the best computer configuration to build a computer cluster. This computer cluster is going to be used for a search engine which uses a lot of quick-access I/O operation, so my top priority is I/O. Of course, I’d like to use SSDs and it would be ideal to use a lot of SSDs in one PC with maximum performance, but I’d like to avoid using external RAID controls because my current budget is a little low (around 4,500$). My other option would be (I think) using multiple PCs with regular configurations and using them in a network.

I’m not familiar with recent technologies used for this purpose, so I turned to you, for your help and I’d like to use your expertise in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many variables to address in one answer. Please review [Nutch](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/) and its documentation about setting up a cluster of instances: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchHadoopTutorial

Answer (score 1):

SSD isn't too good idea for cluster, go for SAS hard drives, it'l provide more stable latency and more disk space for less cost. But you still can use SSD as flash cache to boost performance for a little more